# Elementos Dinamicos de Formularios no Enviados Metodo POST

Tags: php, javascript, formularios

tengo un formulario donde se pueden agregar lineas de manera dinamica.

He armado un array para capturar las variables con el metodo POST pero solo me reconoce las 3 que ya estaban presentes en el HTML en un principio. Las demás que se agregaron de manera dinamica nunca las lee. Es como si nunca hubiesen existido. Como debería proceder?

el formulario

```
        <div>
        <form id="" name="serv_1" method="POST" action="visualiza_form.php" class="row">
        <textarea name="serv_1_linea[]" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <textarea name="serv_1_linea[]" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <textarea name="serv_1_linea[]" class="form-control"></textarea>


        <div id="dynamicDiv"></div>


        <div id="agregar_linea" class="row">


        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" name="previsualizar" value="Previsualizar">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Archivo visualiza_form.php

```
if (isset($_POST['previsualizar'])) {

        $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

        $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];

        $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];

        $serv_1_linea = $_POST['serv_1_linea'];

}
```

Script que agrega los textarea a la dynamicDiv

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
            var count = 4;
            var scntDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');
            $('#add_row').on('click', function() {
              if(count < 17) {
                $('<div class="row item">'+
                            '<div class="col">'+
                                '<textarea id="serv_1_linea_'+ count +'" name="serv_1_linea[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Describa el servicio o producto"></textarea>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>').appendTo(scntDiv).fadeIn(2000);
                count++;
                 }
                else{
                    $("#add_row").off("click");   //remove click listener. 
                    }
            });

            });
```

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_POST['serv_1_linea'])` en `visualiza_form.php` y te debería de aparecer un array con lo que hayas escrito en cada `textarea`, ya hice el ejemplo y si me funciona.

Comment: Solucionado. Con PHP solo no se puede, pues son campos dinámico generados con jQuery. Por lo tanto tuve de poner los campos en un array con el mismo jQuery  y usar Ajax para pasarlo al archivo PHP. Funciona!!

Answer (score 0):

En tu PHP puedes capturar todos los parámetros pasados por POST con solo utilizar `$_POST`;

Por lo que podrías hacer un `foreach` de `$_POST` como tal

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  //
}
```

y ahí accedes a cada campo dinámico que le enviés.

Comment: Sí, el foreach lo tengo hecho, pero aun así. Solo toma los elementos estáticos que ya estaban en la página al momento de cargarla. Y no los que fueron generados dinamicamente despues :( Por ejemplo: si doy un echo $serv_1_linea[2] me muestra su valor, pero si subo el offset a [3] que seria generado dinamicamente ya no lo reconoce. Nunca lo ha recibido. "Notice : Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp..." Ya 2 días llevo en eso me desespero ;'( –

Answer (score 0):

Sí, el foreach lo tengo hecho, pero aun así.

Solo toma los elementos estáticos que ya estaban en la página al momento de cargarla. Y no los que fueron generados dinamicamente despues :(

Por ejemplo: si doy un

echo $serv_1_linea[2]

me muestra su valor, pero si subo el offset a [3]

que seria generado dinamicamente ya no lo reconoce.

Nunca lo ha recibido. "Notice : Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp..."

Ya 2 días llevo en eso me desespero ;'( –